# SQL Server 2008R2 Where Clause to merge two queries

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a query that get back a list of stores that a user has access to. 
Howerver if a user is an internal staff member they automatically have access to all stores.

In the staff table this is indicated by a coloumn called Internal which is represented by 1 for is internal staff and 0 for not an internal staff.

Currently there is a stored proc which gets the list of stores for the user where the userId is passed in. The stored proc is similar to below. So I'm looking to figure out how to join the query into one.

```
    DECLARE @IsInternal bit

    SELECT @IsInternal = Staff.Internal FROM Staff WHERE Staff.StaffId = @userId

 IF(@IsInternal = 0)
   BEGIN
      SELECT DISTINCT Store.Id, Store.Name,
      FROM 
        Store JOIN StaffAccess ON StaffAccess.StoreID = Store.StoreId
              JOIN Staff ON StaffAccess.StaffId= Staff.StaffId
      WHERE
        StaffAccess.StaffID = @userId
      ORDER BY
          Store.Name
   END
ELSE
   BEGIN
        SELECT DISTINCT Store.Id,Store.Name,
        FROM Store
        ORDER BY Store.Name
  END
```

Sorry I should have included there is a staff access table. If I run below it brings back all the stores for the user that is not an internal staff

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        Store.Id,
        Store.Name,

    FROM
        Store
            JOIN StaffAccess ON StaffAccess.StoreID = Store.StoreId
            JOIN Staff on Staff.Internal= 1 OR (StaffAccess.StaffID = @userId        AND StaffAccess.StaffId = Staff.StaffId)   

    ORDER BY
        Store.Name
```

Comment: Can you read your own code with this confusing indenting style? I have a hard time even seeing where the statements start and end.

Comment: Improved the answer with a working example - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/aafa5/16/0

Answer (score 2):

You can have this simple query which solves your requirement

```
SELECT DISTINCT
     Store.storeid,
     Store.Name 
FROM
    Store JOIN Staff ON Staff.StaffID = @UserId 
    AND (Staff.Internal = 1 OR 
         Staff.StoreID = Store.StoreId)
ORDER BY
    Store.Name;
```

Fiddle [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/aafa5/16/0)